# How to get text from one of span elements inside another span element?

Tags: jquery, find, html

I have this part of code:

```
<div id="AjaxFileUpload1_FileInfoContainer_900BDF5B-CE16-296C-46C9-3A679A9CD120" class="pendingState" style="display: inline-block;">
<span id="AjaxFileUpload1_FileItemInfo_900BDF5B-CE16-296C-46C9-3A679A9CD120" class="ajax__fileupload_fileItemInfo">
<span class="filename">Power_Classic_1328174879.hbs</span>  - 
<span class="filesize">4.09 kb</span> 
</span>
<span id="AjaxFileUpload1_FileItemStatus_900BDF5B-CE16-296C-46C9-3A679A9CD120" class="uploadstatus"> (pending*)</span></div>
```

I need to get the file name "Power_Classic_1328174879.hbs" from the code by jQuery, how i can find it?

EDIT:

```
<script>

    $(document).change(function () {
        $(".removeButton").click(function () {
            var idr = $(this).attr('id');
            var idrc = idr.replace('AjaxFileUpload1_FileItemDeleteButton_', '');

            var nazwa = $("span#AjaxFileUpload1_FileItemInfo_" + idrc + " span.filename").text();

            alert(nazwa);
        });
    });
</script>
```

I attach function to remove button click of AjaxFileUpload in ASP.NET. This control dynamically generate buttons for selected files. I get id of button and save it in idr variable, next i get only dynamically generated part od id like "494FDJ-393HD..." and save it in idrc. This part of id repeat in other div, span elements related to one file. Now i need to find filename in code using idrc as a part of span id.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Answer (score 0):

```
var filename = $('.pendingState .ajax__fileupload_fileItemInfo .filename').html();
```

Comment: it doesn't work.. i have a button, when i click it i use alert function to check if the filename appears there, alert says only "undefined"

Answer (score 0):

use `text()`;

try this

```
$('span#AjaxFileUpload1_FileItemInfo_900BDF5B-CE16-296C-46C9-3A679A9CD120 span.filename').text();
```

though your id looks weird , i am using span's id selector since id should be unique and should give you the exact span element you need instead of class(class can be multiple) .

Comment: it doesn't work.. i have a button, when i click it i use alert function to check if the filename appears there, alert doesnt show anything

Comment: please show us your code.. and make sure your id is exacly the same